# What is the diffrence between add_action and add_filter in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

What is the diffrence between add_action and add_filter in wordpress ? when i use action hook and filter hook.

Comment: Here is a [difference between `add_action` and `add_filter`](https://programming-review.com/wordpress/add_filter-hook/).

Answer (score 0):

You can read it here :)

http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/

add_action => call a function

add_filter => "A filter is defined as a function that takes in some kind of input, modifies it, and then returns it."